# How to change all columns value of a matrix in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, slice

As the title says, I want to change all columns value to the same array using no external library besides numpy and without using for, while or something like that because what I'm looking for is efficiency.

I thought I would be able to solve this problem using slices because you can do that for rows.

```py
# Initial matrix
a= [[0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0]]

# Wanted array to replace all columns with
b = [1,2,3]

# Matrix after replacement
a= [[1,1,1],
    [2,2,2],
    [3,3,3]]
```

That's the output that I wanted but for some reason I wasn't able to achieve that yet because I want do it in a simple way. How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using a list comprehension:

```py
a = [ [x]*len(row) for row, x in zip(a, b) ]
```

This creates a new matrix, rather than mutating the matrix in-place. If you want to mutate it in-place, you will need a nested loop:

```py
for row, x in zip(a, b):
    for i in range(len(row)):
        row[i] = x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a= [[0,0,0],
   [0,0,0],
   [0,0,0]]
b = [1,2,3]

for i, value in enumerate(b):
    a[i] = [value]*len(a[i])

print(a)
```

output:

```
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```

Comment: This solution works but there is something strange about it. It updates the matrix `a` in-place, but does so by creating new rows, rather than updating the rows in-place. This could lead to some very subtle bugs if other code holds a reference to one of the rows, which (since it is not updated in-place) will remain full of zeroes. I think you should either update everything in-place, or create a new matrix without mutating the old one; doing a mix of both is probably not as useful.

Comment: I dont see why that can be a problem. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Suppose we define `a` with the zeroes, then we define `a_alias = a` and `a_row_alias = a[0]`. When updating `a`, either the update should be "in-place", meaning the contents of `a_alias` and `a_row_alias` change too because they are simply aliases to the data which was updated, *or* the update should be "out-of-place", in which case `a_alias` and `a_row_alias` still refer to the old matrix with zeroes in. When your code runs, `a_alias` now has the values from `b` in it, but `a_row_alias` still has zeroes; that would be surprising and possibly a source of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Your a list is invalid so I assumed you meant a to a list of 3 lists

```py
a = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
]

b = [1, 2, 3]

for counter, value in enumerate(b):
    a[counter] = [value for i in a[counter]]

print(a)
```

enumerate gives you the counter for free.

note if there are more elements in b than a this will throw index out of range error, so if you are not sure, check the length before replacing.

Comment: instead of using list comprehension to create a list. You can just use `[value]*length` syntax.

Comment: This solution works but there is something strange about it. It updates the matrix `a` in-place, but does so by creating new rows, rather than updating the rows in-place. This could lead to some very subtle bugs if other code holds a reference to one of the rows, which (since it is not updated in-place) will remain full of zeroes. I think you should either update everything in-place, or create a new matrix without mutating the old one; doing a mix of both is probably not as useful.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great to get more context for this question, because there is currently very little to go off of. For example, how much control do you have over arrays `a` and `b`? This operation might not even be necessary in the first place.

For now, here is a solution that works when the arrays are similar to those in your example.

```py
import numpy as np


arr_1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])

arr_1_col = arr_1.reshape((-1, 1))

arr_2 = np.tile(A=arr_1_col, reps=3)
```

**Note:** You mention NumPy in your question, I cannot recommend it enough. As soon as you're doing these kinds of tasks, switching to numpy arrays is hugely beneficial.

Answer (score -1):

It is simpler to create new matrix than actually replace columns 'in-place'.
I assume your matrix is square.

```
length = len(b)
a = [ [b[i]] * length for i in range(length) ]
```

Result

```
   [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```

Now, following multiple requests of concerned commenters I add a solution for the rectangular A:

```
length = len(b)
width = len(a[0])
a = [ [b[i]] * width for i in range(length) ]
```

or, in more pythonic style

```
width = len(a[0])
a = [ [x] * width for x in b ]
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. Have you tested it?

Comment: Better, but you're assuming the matrix is always square. The question doesn't guarantee this. You should also explain your answer; don't just post code.

Comment: This is totally wrong. It will fail for `a= [[0],   [0],   [0]]` `b = [1,2,3]`. Length of `b` tells you height of `a` not the `width` of `a`. You can never guess `width` from `b` in this case

Comment: @kaya3 Yup I assume square matrix. Why else would topic starter supply a square one in the example? Anyways you put the generalization of my solution in your answer

Comment: @Poojan, in which way it will possibly fail

Comment: @Serge i gave you the example. Run that

Comment: Do not see a need. The outcome would not change

Comment: If you assume that the real data will always look like your example data, you are going to write a lot of buggy software. Never assume what isn't in the specification.